# Timer.Tick event handler not getting event Timer_Tick in Timer

Tags: c#, timer

Hi I am working with Windows.Forms.Timer with Web Application . I create Timer.Tick event handler to handle Timer_Tick but I am not successfull. I don't get any error but I can not get result even. Here is my code

```
     System.Windows.Forms.Timer StopWatchTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

public void StopwatchStartBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    StopWatchTimer.Enabled = true;
    StopWatchTimer.Interval = 1;
    StopWatchTimer.Start();
    this.StopWatchTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(StopWatchTimer1_Tick);
    sw.Start();
}


protected void StopWatchStopBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    StopWatchTimer.Stop();
    sw.Reset();
    StopWatchLbl.Text = "00:00:00:000";
}

public void StopWatchTimer1_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan elapsed = sw.Elapsed;
    StopWatchLbl.Text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}", 
                            Math.Floor(elapsed.TotalHours), 
                            elapsed.Minutes, 
                            elapsed.Seconds, 
                            elapsed.Milliseconds);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the WinForms `Timer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer`?

Comment: What is StopWatchTimer vs sw?

Comment: DeviantSeev I believe has the answer but just to verify what's the difference between StopWatchTimer and sw?

Comment: Yes I can use System.timer instead of winforms .I didn't think about that.I will try that now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the MSDN documentation for Windows Forms Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) (emphasis mine):

Implements a timer that raises an event at user-defined intervals. This timer is optimized for use in Windows Forms applications and **must be used in a window**.

This timer will not work in a web application.  You'll need to use another class, like [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).  This has it's own pitfalls, however.

Comment: Easily googled, but here you go: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/DemonstratesusingtheSystemTimersTimerclass2.htm

Answer (score 1):

Did you try defining the Tick event prior to starting the timer?

```
this.StopWatchTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(StopWatchTimer1_Tick);    
StopWatchTimer.Start();
```

Comment: This is the correct way to use a timer but I missed the part where you're trying to use it for a web application. Please refer to other answers in regards to your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class TestFrom : Form
{
    private Thread threadP;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer Timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    private string str;

    public TestFrom()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer.Interval =100;
        Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimeBussiness);
        Timer.Enabled = true;
        Timer.Start();
        Timer.Tag = "Start";
    }

    void TimeBussiness(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (threadP.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
        {
            Timer.Stop();
            Timer.Tag = "Stop";
        }
        else
        {
            //do my bussiness1;
        }
     }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(Salver);
        threadP= new Thread(threadStart);
        threadP.Start();
    }

    private void Salver()
    {
        while (Timer.Tag == "Stop")
        {

        }
        //do my bussiness2;
        Timer.Start();
        Timer.Tag = "Start";
    }
}
```